# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html, ampscript

I am using amp-script to create an animation on my AMP page.

```js
var sentences = ["I‘m not getting any impressions", "I‘m getting impressions but no clicks", "I‘m getting clicks but no conversions", "My wasted spend is increasing", "My keywords are not performing", "My cost per click is increasing", "My ad is not showing in the top position", "My ROI is declining"];
var index = 0;
var reverse = false;
setInterval(myTimer1, 1);

function myTimer1() {
  if (!reverse) {
    sleep(120);
  } else {
    sleep(60);
  }
  sentenseAnimation(sentences[index]);
}

function sentenseAnimation(sentense) {
  if (document.querySelector(".txtex").innerHTML == "") {
    sleep(1000);
  }
  var s = document.querySelector(".txtex").innerHTML;
  if (s.length != sentense.length && !reverse) {
    s = s + sentense.charAt(s.length)
  } else {
    if (!reverse) {
      sleep(1000);
    }
    reverse = true
    s = s.slice(0, -1);
    if (s.length == 0) {
      reverse = false;
      if (index < sentences.length - 1) {
        index++;
      } else {
        index = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  document.querySelector(".txtex").innerHTML = s;
}

function sleep(delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

The animation runs smoothly but after 5 to 6 hours the animation stops and gives an error(Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method) in amp-script.js.
[image]

Comment: please format your code using a prettier before posting here.

Comment: See AMP documentation. There is a duration limit for `amp-script`. That may be your issue.